# I know how to add an item to ie right click menu, but how to get current page's element?

Tags: internet-explorer

How to add an item to i.e. right click menu：

```
run cmd -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Microsoft -> Internet Explorer -> MenuExt -> New an Item, Then set 
the Default's value with a file's path (for example: D:\test.html)
```

But, I want to get current page user's username and telephone in the D:\test.html, that I can open a new tab, this new tab has the username and telephone, so I can print the username and telephone by printer

the code in D:\test.html below cannot works, you know what I want to do :-):

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById("hello").value);
</script>
</html>
```

And below is the page which right click on it

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="hello">hello, stackoverflow！</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i run it, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5DEA.jpg)

but it alerts an error：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NTUt.png)

### ------------------------------------------------------------

This issue has been resolved,  the html page below is what i want. bookmarklet is the suitable method.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG2rS.png)

Comment: Could you please provide the related code in test.html? How does the username and telephone elements look like? How do you get the values? If you want to get the value of the element, it should be something like `document.getElementById("hello").value;`. I tested in my side and it can work well, so it could be better if you provide [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can have a better understanding of the issue and see how to help.

Comment: hi, i have updated this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script can't work because it can't get the value of an element in another page. The script is in page1, but the element is in page2, so it can't get the element.

In your case, you should use [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) instead of IE menu. Use the below script in your bookmarklet to get the element value:

```
javascript: (function () { alert(document.getElementById("hello").value); })();
```

Use the below steps to add a bookmarklet:

1. Open any page in IE and use **Alt+C** to call the favorites bar.
2. Click **Add to favorites** and give your bookmarklet a name then click Add.
   [image]
3. Open the favorites bar and find the bookmarklet you added just now, right click on it and click **Properties**.
4. Add the script I give above to the **URL** of the bookmarklet Properties, click Apply OK.
   [image]

The outcome is like below:
[image]

Comment: @TheZ If it solves your issue, you could [mark it as an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.